# Understanding jQuery draggable

Tags: jquery

```
$(".item").draggable({
    revert: true            
});
$("#cart_items").draggable({
    axis: "x"
});

$("#cart_items").droppable({


    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var item = ui.draggable.html();
            console.log(item);

        var html = '<div class="item icart">';
        html = html + '<div class="divrm">';
        html = html + '<a onclick="remove(this)" class="remove">&times;</a>';
        html = html + '<div/>'+item+'</div>';
        $("#cart_items").append(html);+
```

I understand that with `var html` I am creating all html and appending it to the DOM, but why I need this? `var item = ui.draggable.html();` What does `ui.draggable` stands for?

Comment: From the [docu](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop) _In the callback, $(this) represents the droppable the draggable is dropped on. **ui.draggable represents the draggable**_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, `ui` is the passed in object. `ui` happens to be an event. This event has a property `draggable`. Lastly `.html()` gets the inner HTML of the object.

The line `var item = ui.draggable.html();` equates to:

`item` equals the object `ui`'s property `draggable`'s inner HTML contents.

From the structure of the function I would assume the `ui` event is a drag and drop opperation and that the `draggable` content is an item for an e-commerce shopping cart.